# asynchronously loading images in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image that I want shown at the top of the view in a table view cell.

I have the following code that asynchronously loads that image and adds it to the cell:

```
 if let image = value?["image"]  {
                            let bookImageUrl =  URL(string: image as! String)
                            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: bookImageUrl!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                if data != nil {
                                    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data!));
                                    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                             y: 95,
                                                             width: cell.frame.size.width,
                                                             height: 150)
                                    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                                    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                                    cell.addSubview(imageView)

                                    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10,
                                                                      y: cell.frame.size.height-60,
                                                                      width: cell.frame.size.width,
                                                                      height: 50));
                                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                                    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
                                    label.font = UIFont(name: "CeraPro-Bold", size: 16)
                                    label.text = "  \(title)"
                                    cell.addSubview(label)
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Unfortunately, sometimes the image does not get loaded. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're lazy like me and are allowed to use 3rd party frameworks, you could just use a framework like Kingfisher to do it. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: Just eyeballing your code, where's your network call?

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5293-operation-and-operationqueue-tutorial-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)` in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, here UITableView do reusing of those cells [dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell)

So as with the problem you mentioned is with some times the images do not get shown, this might be because of the `UITableView` is reusing the cells, so, it will be better if you use `else` for every `if` statement. Or you can use something like, [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) or [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) for image caching.

Also note that, as the `UITableView` does reuse every cell so it will be better to remove all subviews or create a variable in class for 'UITableViewCell' before adding any view over programmatically, as in your code `cell.addSubview(imageView)` and `cell.addSubview(label)` the `imageView` and `label` is getting initialized and added over and over for every reuse and every URL check, Here what you can do is create a variable for `label` and `imageview` in the cell and initialize only if the variable is `nil` and assign the image afterwards.